# Reverse Lookup Messaging Service from Phone Number SID Via API

Tags: twilio-api

I'm an ISV account and I need to check whether certain phone number SIDs are attached to a messaging service and use that messaging service SID.

I can only found the the [list all messaging services end point](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api#read-multiple-service-resources).

But since I'm not using sub accounts this will return all my users messaging services (1,000s), is there another, more efficient way to achieve this look up (PN to MG)?